# Changing GPU name to bypass game hardware checkers

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, windows-registry, gpu, bypass

I recently  revived my old HP laptop (Pavilion dm4) and it has integrated Intel HD 3000 graphics. I went ahead and installed Overwatch . I try to launch the game, but it has a hardware checker. The minimum GPU the game accepts is an Intel HD 4000. The game won't launch.

I know there is a way to change your driver name in the registry, to fool the checker (Like changing how my computer reads it as Intel HD 3000 to like a titan x). I can run the game, my processor is powerful, and Overwatch is a CPU based game. I didn't want to mess with anything in the registry because I know I can severely hurt my laptop.

I just want to trick the checker so I can just play the game. I'm on windows 10.

Comment: What you want to attempt will not work.  Even if you tricked the software into starting, the application would eventually crash, due to the software attempting to do something your hardware does not support.

Comment: The possible reason for it not supporting the HD 3000 could be the same one as why Intel didn't make a Win 10 driver for it. It's now abandonware.

Answer (score 0):

It won't do any damage.  I play that game and I have Intel 3000 so I went into the registry (It will not damage your laptop) and changed mine to GeForce RTX 2070 and I bypassed it!

Comment: The thread opener excluded changes in the registry as part of the solution.